# Не находит путь к странице авторизации

Tags: ruby-on-rails

При использовании rails_admin, возникла потребность ограничить доступ к ней не авторизованным пользователям и пользователям, не являющимися администраторами. При попытке зайти пользователь должен редиректиться на страницу авторизации.

для этого в `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` прописал согласно документации:

```
  config.authorize_with do
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: "Not an admin" unless (current_user && warden.user.admin == true)
  end
```

но при заходе на страницу `localhost:3000/admin` выбивает ошибку:

`` undefined local variable or method `new_user_session_path' for #<RailsAdmin::MainController:0x00000003f4fd50> Did you mean? new_session_path ``

выхлоп `rake routes`

```
                      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
             rails_admin        /admin                         RailsAdmin::Engine
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      
         ...

Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
  dashboard GET         /                                      rails_admin/main#dashboard
      index GET|POST    /:model_name(.:format)                 rails_admin/main#index
        new GET|POST    /:model_name/new(.:format)             rails_admin/main#new
     export GET|POST    /:model_name/export(.:format)          rails_admin/main#export
bulk_delete POST|DELETE /:model_name/bulk_delete(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_delete
bulk_action POST        /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_action
       show GET         /:model_name/:id(.:format)             rails_admin/main#show
       edit GET|PUT     /:model_name/:id/edit(.:format)        rails_admin/main#edit
     delete GET|DELETE  /:model_name/:id/delete(.:format)      rails_admin/main#delete
show_in_app GET         /:model_name/:id/show_in_app(.:format) rails_admin/main#show_in_app
```

также смотрел через `rails console`:

```
irb(main):001:0> include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
=> Object
irb(main):002:0> new_user_session_path
=> "/users/sign_in"
```

Перезагружал сервер и spring.

Comment: @Nakilon Описывая правку, пожалуйста используйте комментарий по назначению.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте префикс `main_app.`, когда вам нужно сослаться на роут основного приложения изнутри рельсоадмина, и префикс `rails_admin.` - если наоборот.
То есть, в вашем случае будет

```
redirect_to main_app.new_user_session_path
```

Это происходит из-за того, что рельсоадмин монтируется к основному приложению в виде engine'а, у него есть свои собственные роуты, и как-то их надо различать.

Чуть подробнее [здесь](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Using-RailsAdmin-routes) и [здесь](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes)

Comment: И вновь выручили. Спасибо.
я думал насквозь прошелся по этой документации